# How to understand leetcode 494 Target Sum ( knapsack problem ) fastest python code using bit operation

Tags: python

The problem is described as follows
https://leetcode.com/problems/target-sum/

> You are given a list of non-negative integers, a1, a2, ..., an, and a target, S. Now you have 2 symbols + and -. For each integer, you should choose one from + and - as its new symbol.
>
> Find out how many ways to assign symbols to make sum of integers equal to target S.
>
> Constraints:
>
> - The length of the given array is positive and will not exceed 20.
> - The sum of elements in the given array will not exceed 1000.
> - Your output answer is guaranteed to be fitted in a 32-bit integer.

I find this submission in leetcode submission detail Accepted Solutions Runtime Distribution

```py
class Solution:
    def findTargetSumWays(self, nums, S):
        a = sum(nums) - S
        if a < 0 or a%2==1: return 0 
        S = [((1<<(i*21))+1) for i in nums]
        return reduce(lambda p,i:(p*i)&(1<<((a//2+1)*21))-1,S,1)>>(21*a//2)
```

Simplify reduce, it becomes

```py
class Solution:
    def findTargetSumWays(self, nums, S):
        a = sum(nums) - S
        if a < 0 or a%2==1: return 0 
        auxarr = [((1<<(i*21))+1) for i in nums]
        ret=1
        for i in auxarr:
            ret= (ret*i)&(1<<((a//2+1)*21))-1
        return ret>>(21*a//2)
```

It transforms the original problem into another problem that finds the number of selections that select some `nums[i]` that their sum is `(sum(nums)-S)/2`.

I know how to solve such knapsack problems with dp, but I can't understand the above code, I am very curious how such code works, please help me.

```py
# my dp code
class Solution:
    def findTargetSumWays(self, nums: List[int], S: int) -> int:
        S=sum(nums)-S
        if S%2!=0 or S<0: return 0
        S//=2
        dp=[0]*(S+1)
        dp[0]=1
        for c in nums:
            for j in range(S,c-1,-1):
                dp[j]+=dp[j-c]
        return dp[S]
```

Comment: You can treat `ret` and elements of `auxarr` as lists of zeros and ones. `((1<<(i*21))+1)` will correspond to a list, in which elements at positions 0 and i*21 are ones and the rest are zeros

Comment: Or better as a list of integers in range [0, 2^21) instead of bits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to use characteristics of a polynomial where you multiply terms formed of (B^n+1) where B is a power of 2 large enough to avoid overlapping.

So, let's say you have 3 numbers (x,y,z) to add, it will compute:

```
(B^x + 1)(B^y + 1)(B^z + 1)
```

The exponents of these polynomials will add up in the result

```
B^(x+y+z) + B^(x+z) + B^(y+z) + B^z + B^(x+y) + B^x + B^y + 1
```

So, if any combination of exponent (i.e. numbers) adds up to the same total, the number of times B^total occurs will be the number of ways to obtain that total.  Leveraging this characteristic of polynomials, we will find ways*B^total in the result. If the number of ways does not overlap with the value of B^(total+1), it can be extracted using masks and integer divisions.

For example, given 4 numbers h,i,j,k, the products will produce the sum of B raised to powers corresponding to every combination of 1 up to 4 of the numbers added together.   So, if we are looking for a total of T, and h+i and j+k equal T.  Then the product will contain 2*B^T formed by B^(h+i) + B^(j+k).  This corresponds to two ways to form the sum T.

Given that there are 2 possibility for each number (+ or -), there is a maximum of 2^20 possible ways to combine them. To make sure that any sum of B^x does not overlap with B^(x+1), the value of 2^21 is chosen for B.

This is why the offset array (variable name S is a really poor choice here) is formed of (B^n+1) for each n in nums, where B is 2^21, so (2^21^n+1) ... (2^(21n)+1) ... `(1<<(21*n))+1`

To be able to use the polynomial approach, the problem needs to be converted to an Absence/Presence problem. This is done by reasoning that there has to be a combination of numbers that produces a zero sum by cancelling each other out, leaving the rest to be positive and add up to S.  So, if we remove S from the total of numbers, there will be a combination that adds up to half of what remains (`a//2`). This will be the total we will be looking for.

The `reduce` function implements the polynomial product and applies a mask (`(1<<((a//2+1)*21))-1`) to cut off any power of B that is beyond B^(a/2).  The final result cuts off the part below B^(a/2) by shifting bits.

This results in the multiple of B^(a/2) which corresponds to the number of ways to produce the sum of exponents (i.e the sum of numbers).